# css min() not compatible with android firefox and opera, an alternative?

Tags: css, reactjs

i work on front end website who should be responsive ( with ReactJs ),
i use a lot of `min()` in my css but i noticed it's not compatible with Opera & Firefox on Android when i put the site on dev-online

i use it to calculate fontSize, padding:

```
fontSize: "min(5vw,34px)",
paddingRight: "min(28px , 5vw)",
width: "min(40vw,270px)",
height: "min(40vw,270px)" ,
minWidth: "min(45vw,900px)",
maxWidth: "max(35vw,700px)",
```

How to use a `fallback` value ?

this for example does'nt work ( min() look like to overide the constant value but it is not applied ):

```
fontSize: "34px",
fontSize: "min(5vw,34px)",

paddingRight: "28px",
paddingRight: "min(28px , 5vw)",

width: "270px",
width: "min(40vw,270px)",

height: "270px" ,
height: "min(40vw,270px)" ,

minWidth: "45vw",
minWidth: "min(45vw,900px)",

maxWidth: "700px",
maxWidth: "max(35vw,700px)",
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be semi-colons and not commas?

Comment: It's reactjs way to right style with materialui (replacing also '-' with camelcase)